# Go set seed for map iteration order

Tags: go

In go, map iteration order is not specified, and may vary from run to run. Is there any way to set a seed for this, such that two runs of the same go program will have consistent iteration order?

Comment: Not actually. You can try to sort your keys and iterate over them. Or use a third party package that implements an ordered map, for example: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/wk8/go-ordered-map

Comment: Map iteration is deliberately made random so that nobody can start relying on iteration order. What you ask for would undermine this effort and allow persons to rely on iteration order and encourage people to write bad code.

Answer (score 2):

**Brief:**
Use official `range + map` is impossible, but you can use 3rd party libraries, as mentioned in the comments.

**Why:**
As you can see from here [go/src/runtime/map.go#mapiterinit](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/41d8e61a6b9d8f9db912626eb2bbc535e929fefc/src/runtime/map.go#L832), the traversal of the map uses [go/src/runtime/stubs.go#fastrand](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/41d8e61a6b/src/runtime/stubs.go#L109) to randomly choose the starting position, but the result of `fastrand()` is changed every time, you can't decide the order each time.

It is recommended to briefly read the important parts of the posted source code, everything is very simple and clear.